# Does Google Dialogflow support videos?

Tags: dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger

I had integrated dialogflow with Facebook messenger recently. So far i am able to insert images such as JPG and GIF in the chatbot. Is it possible to insert short videos into the chatbot? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to found the solution after reading the fb documentation

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "video",
      "payload": {
        "url": "www.samplevideo123.mp4"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can upload video using messenger bot so how to get in dialog-flow web-hook